# Browsing to web page, typing in text to search bar, and searching... but the text disappears when I click the search button

Tags: excel, vba, screen-scraping

First post here. Tried looking for similar posts but wasn't able to turn up anything.

I'm a little new to VBA. I'm trying to use Excel to navigate to a specific website, click a radio button, type in some text as a search string, and then search on that text. Everything seems fine when I walk through my code, but when I click the search button my search string gets blanked out and I get an error message telling me to enter search criteria. Code below:

```
Sub FranklinCountyWebsite()
'References: Microsoft Internet Controls, Microsoft HTML Object Library

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://sheriff.franklincountyohio.gov/real-estate/"

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.document

HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_SheetContentPlaceHolder_c_search1_rblSrchOptions_3").Click
HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_SheetContentPlaceHolder_c_search1_SrchSearchString").Value = "43215"
HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_SheetContentPlaceHolder_c_search1_btnSearch").Click

End Sub
```

Interestingly, if I go to the Franklin County website and type in the text manually and then hit search, everything works fine. Is there something easy I'm overlooking?

Comment: It can help to set the focus on a control before clicking on it.

Comment: Got it to work -- much appreciated. I added 

"HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_SheetContentPlaceHolder_c_search1_SrchSearchString").Focus" 

before the part where I set the search string to a specific value.

Comment: Ok, cool, excellent.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the same using `serverxmlhttp` request which is way faster than IE. The below script can lead you to the target page where you wished to get data from.

```
Sub Fetch_Item()
    Dim post As Object, qsp$, S$

    qsp = "q=searchType%3dZipCode%26searchString%3d43215%26foreclosureType%3d%26sortType%3daddress%26saleDateFrom%3d4%2f30%2f2017+12%3a00%3a00+AM%26saleDateTo%3d10%2f30%2f2018+11%3a59%3a59+PM"

    With New ServerXMLHTTP
        .Open "GET", "https://sheriff.franklincountyohio.gov/real-estate/results.aspx?" & qsp, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With New HTMLDocument
        .body.innerHTML = S
        Set post = .getElementById("ctl00_SheetContentPlaceHolder_C_searchresults_reSaleSummary_ctl00_lblAddrHeader")
        MsgBox post.innerText
    End With
End Sub
```

Output:

```
 155-157 CLEVELAND AVE COLUMBUS, OH 43215 010054688, 010055721
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft XML, V6.0
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: Hey @SIM

I appreciate it. When I asked this question a week ago I was just trying to get everything working with IE and get a cursory understanding of using VBA for web scraping, but I saw your comment yesterday and started looking into using the XML library to speed things up. Thanks!

Comment: Nice answer as usual